# Mysql group by with count 0 and where in clause

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to get the count values present in the same SQL table.
I have a table `abc`  and I want to count of values present in table.

example: [image]

**my query** :

```
select name, count(*) as count 
from table abc 
where name in ('a','b', 'd','f') 
group by name;
```

expected Output :[image]

Comment: Here's a clue: `SELECT 'a' name UNION SELECT 'b' UNION SELECT 'd' UNION SELECT 'f'`

Comment: ... i.e. if you want to do this in one query then desired names list must be a rowset in FROM, not literals list in WHERE.

Comment: I'm confused is the first table your source data ? if so why isn't c in the output and where did d and f come from.

Comment: d and f came from where clause, I'm picking a user based on how many records present in table but some users may not present in table so I want count 0 if users not present in my table but I'm using users in wherecaluse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try next solution:

```
SELECT col, COUNT(abc.name) cnt
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    '["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]',
    "$[*]" COLUMNS(
        col CHAR(1) PATH "$"
    )
) AS  jt1 -- virtual table 
LEFT JOIN abc ON abc.name = jt1.col
GROUP BY col;
```

Here [SQL online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=c81b74922825e8f4f0f9ad7b8f53cba4&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

For legacy MySQL temporary table can be used as solution:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE chars (
    letter CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO chars VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e'), ('f');

SELECT letter, COUNT(abc.name) cnt
FROM chars
LEFT JOIN abc ON abc.name = chars.letter
GROUP BY letter;
```

[SQL query online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2e40f1bd32985a55579ffb34a61977c5&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: This solution worked in MySQL version 8 but I'm using the 5.7 version and it is not working. Thanks for the solutions

Comment: Added legacy solution